# powershell script can't find a file that exists

Tags: powershell

I have this script that creates files using bcp. As BCP doesn't export data with header i need to join both files into. If i run the code in another script it creates the csv file but if i run this script it fails saying files DOES NOT EXIST, that is the last section of the script below (#THE PROBLEM STARTS HERE).
Appreciate any help.

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:ErrorAction']='Stop'

$bcp = 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe'
$delimiter = '","'
$server = 'BLABLABLA'
$database = 'DMB'
$schema = '.dbo.'
$dbschema = $database + $schema
$atresult = "@result"
$commas = " + ',','') + "
$head1 = 'Use '
$head2 = ' Declare ' # atresult
$head3 = ' varchar(max) select ' # atresult
$head4 = ' = COALESCE(' #atresult $commas
$head5 = 'COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ' # tablename
$head6 = ' select ' #atresult
$tables = @('EntityTypes_20181205','FieldFieldTypeInfo')
$output_path = 'D:\Temp\DataModelBuild\'
# Deletes any file in Destination Folder
#if ( (Get-ChildItem $output_path | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0) {}
Get-ChildItem -Path $output_path -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}    


foreach ($element in $tables) 
    {
        # GET COLUMN NAMES into header file
        $outputFile = $output_path + $element + ".header"
        $NQ = '"' + $head1 + $database + $head2 + $atresult + $head3 + $atresult + $head4 + $atresult + $commas + $head5 + ''' + $element + ''' + $head6 + $atresult + '"'
        #$arglist = "(" + $NQ + " queryout " + $outputFile + ", -S " + $server + " -T -t" + $delimiter + " -c -k)"
        $arglist  = @('"',
                      $head1,
                      $database,
                      $head2,
                      $atresult,
                      $head3,
                      $atresult,
                      $head4,
                      $atresult,
                      $commas,
                      $head5,
                      "'$element'",
                      $head6,
                      $atresult,
                      '"',
                      " queryout $outputFile",
                      "-S $server -T -t$delimiter -c -k")
        #write-output $arglist
        Start-Process -FilePath $bcp -ArgumentList $arglist
        #Read-Host

        # GET DATA into data file
        $outElement = $dbschema + "[" + $element + "]"
        $outputFile = $output_path + $element + ".data"
        $arglist  = @($outElement, "out $outputFile", "-S $server -T -t$delimiter -c -k")
        Start-Process -FilePath $bcp -ArgumentList $arglist
        #write-output $arglist
        #Read-Host
        # Merge header and data to csv
        #Invoke-Expression "&'$ExtPs1' -FilePath $output_path -FileName $element"
        #Write-Output "call "
        #Invoke-Expression "&'D:\idna\PedroTemp\cp2csv.ps1' $output_path $element"
        #Read-Host

        #THE PROBLEM STARTS HERE       
        $File1 = @("$output_path$element.header")
        $File2 = @("$output_path$element.data")
        $File3 = @("$output_path$element.csv")
        write-output $File1, $File2, $File3
        If (-not (Test-Path -Path $File1)) {
                    Write-Error "File DOES NOT EXIST '$File1'" -ErrorAction Stop
                    } else {
                    Write-Host "File EXIST"
                    }
        Add-Content $File3 -value (Get-Content $File1)
        Add-Content $File3 -value (Get-Content $File2)
        #write-output $File1, $File2, $File3 -ErrorAction Stop
        Read-Host
}
```

My question is why isn't the script detecting the file?
Is there any problem with the string?

Comment: it looks like you have `[]` in the file name. you will need to use `-LiteralPath` to see that properly.

Comment: Lee, how would you suggest me to use -LiteralPath?

Comment: you would use it in items like `Get-ChildItem`. have you looked at the help at all? [*frown*] try TheFriendlyHelpSystem ... `Get-Help *literalpath*` and then pick one of the commands you have the error with ... perhaps something like `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter LiteralPath` ... and read TheFriendlyHelpSystem.

Answer (score 0):

The strings for the pathes aren't build correctly. When you use a member in a string you have to enclose the variable and the member with `$()`.

```
$File1 = "$output_path$($element.header)"
```

Comment: Just to make clear, .header, .data and .csv are file extensions, that i am using just to identify the files.
With your suggestion, $File1 = "$output_path$($element.header)", i am getting the error:
The property 'header' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.

Comment: Ok if it's the extension, you build the string correctly. It will create an array with the single Item `D:\Temp\DataModelBuild\EntityTypes_20181205.header`. You said this file exists?

Comment: Yes files exists i can see the files (.header and .data) being created. The error comes when i try to concatenate both files into .csv. That's why i've wrote the if to check if file exists.

Comment: which of the lines of your code does throw that error? What happenes when you execute a code that just concatenates them with fixed pathes?

Comment: The code where i get the error is, the last section of script:
        $File1 = @("$output_path$element.header")
        $File2 = @("$output_path$element.data")
        $File3 = @("$output_path$element.csv")
        write-output $File1, $File2, $File3
        If (-not (Test-Path -Path $File1)) {
                    Write-Error "File DOES NOT EXIST $File1" -ErrorAction Stop
                    } else {
                    Write-Host "File EXIST"
                    }
        Add-Content $File3 -value (Get-Content $File1)
        Add-Content $File3 -value (Get-Content $File2)

Comment: The error is:
C:\idna\scripts\DataBuildModel.ps1 : File DOES NOT EXIST D:\temp\EntityTypes_20181205.header
At C:\idna\scripts\DataBuildModel.ps1:93 char:21
+                     Write-Error "File DOES NOT EXIST $File1" -ErrorAction Stop
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DataBuildModel.ps1

Comment: There is the Problem: your path here is ` D:\temp\EntityTypes_20181205.header` but the path in your code shows `$output_path = 'D:\Temp\DataModelBuild\'` one subfolder is missing.

Comment: Your comment is correct. i deleted from the comment box not from the script.
I've created a script with the bottom (problematic) section and it works ok. Checks the files ok and merges to the csv file successfully.

Comment: In combination, as one script, keeps "telling" me that files don't exist. Thanks for your help but for the moment i will try a new approach